# regular expression to match a string that represents a date in spanish

Tags: php, regex

I need to use a regular expression to validate a string (written in spanish) that represents a full date string... I don't need to validate if the actual string is a valid date (leap years, etc...)

The string looks like this:

```
23 de septiembre del 2003

23 de septiembre de 1965
```

If the year is greater then 2000, the the word 'del' is use prior to the year, if not the word 'de' is use...

i did my research and found how to get the first 2 digits:

```
$pattern = ([0-9]+);
```

.. then i got lost on how to put it all together...

Help !

Comment: ~((\d{1,2}) de ([a-z]+) (del?) (\d{4}))~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/\b\d{1,2} de [a-z]+ (de 1\d{3}|del 2\d{3})/i
```

Explanation:

```
\b              ... requires a word boundary, since the following character is a digit
                    (and thus a word character) this will only match if the date is
                    preceded by a character that is not a letter, not a digit and
                    not an underscore
\d{1,2}         ... one or two digits
de              ... literally "de"
[a-z]+          ... any letter from a-z, at least once but an arbitrary number of times
(de 1\d{3}      ... literally "de" followed by "1" and 3 more digits
|               ... or
del 2\d{3})     ... literally "del" followed by "2" and 3 more digits

i               ... make the whole thing case-insensitive (you can omit this if needed)
```

Also note, that all spaces in the regex are treated just like any other character.

Alternatively, instead of `[a-z]+` you could specify a list of valid months like

```
/\b\d{1,2} de (...|septiembre|...) (de 1\d{3}|del 2\d{3})/i
```

(replace ... with more month names an `|` to separate them)

Comment: '234 de enero del 2003' matches... it looks like the expression validates even if the first part is 3 digits? why?

Comment: maybe php doesnt see it as a digit but a string?

Comment: @Marco oh, I see. it matches because it matches only the "34" and ignores the 2. you could add a word-boundary at the front (I'll edit it into the answer)

Comment: thanks m-buettner. that one works! by the way i've look into it and ive change the expression so it only accepts days between 1 and 31: /[1-31] de [a-z]+ (de 1\d{3}|del 2\d{3})/i...i believe that [1-31] is how you do it right?

Comment: Patteren should start with ^ and end with $. Like this '/^\d{1,2} de [a-z]+ (de 1\d{3}|del 2\d{3})$/i'

Comment: perfect! i believe the right way to match a number from 1 to 31 is [1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]

Comment: @glavić I wasn't sure whether the date should be the only thing in the string, or whether dates were supposed to be found in a longer string.

Comment: @Marco yeah, the latter one would work. however you can simplify like this [1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01] ... it's not a big deal though